# Как с помощью bat-файла добавить слово в строки файла?

Tags: файлы, bat

Как с помощью батника проходить по файлу с примерно следующим содержимым (там таких строчек много):

```
INSERT INTO data.weld VALUES (34, 1, NULL, NULL, 20, 1, 8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Стык 113', '12 °С', '113', 6);
INSERT INTO data.weld VALUES (8, 1, NULL, NULL, 6, 1, 8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, '2020-08-04 00:00:00+03', 'Стык 1-1', '12 °С', '9-1-1', 1);
INSERT INTO data.weld VALUES (11, 1, 2, NULL, 6, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, '750*60', '2', 1, '780*8', '3', NULL, NULL, 'Стык 1-4', '10 °С', '9-1-4', 1);

INSERT INTO data.weld_qc_method VALUES (2, 1, 'МИ1', 12, 1, NULL, 15, NULL, 'N', 3);
INSERT INTO data.weld_qc_method VALUES (3, 9, 'НК 1-2', 1, 3, '2020-03-10 00:00:00+03', 15, 24, 'Y', 1);
INSERT INTO data.weld_qc_method VALUES (6, 9, 'НК 1-2-1', 1, 3, '2020-03-10 00:00:00+03', 15, 24, 'Y', 2);
```

И добавлять слово "_temp" после "data.*название таблицы*", чтобы файл выглядел так:

```
INSERT INTO data.weld_temp VALUES (34, 1, NULL, NULL, 20, 1, 8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Стык 113', '12 °С', '113', 6);
INSERT INTO data.weld_temp VALUES (8, 1, NULL, NULL, 6, 1, 8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, '2020-08-04 00:00:00+03', 'Стык 1-1', '12 °С', '9-1-1', 1);
INSERT INTO data.weld_temp VALUES (11, 1, 2, NULL, 6, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, '750*60', '2', 1, '780*8', '3', NULL, NULL, 'Стык 1-4', '10 °С', '9-1-4', 1);

INSERT INTO data.weld_qc_method_temp VALUES (2, 1, 'МИ1', 12, 1, NULL, 15, NULL, 'N', 3);
INSERT INTO data.weld_qc_method_temp VALUES (3, 9, 'НК 1-2', 1, 3, '2020-03-10 00:00:00+03', 15, 24, 'Y', 1);
INSERT INTO data.weld_qc_method_temp VALUES (6, 9, 'НК 1-2-1', 1, 3, '2020-03-10 00:00:00+03', 15, 24, 'Y', 2);
```

Пробовал проходить по строкам файла и искать подстроку "data.*название таблицы*" следующим образом:

```
@FOR /F %%x IN ('findstr "\<data.*" *.* C:\dump.sql') DO ...
```

Но это не работает. Что я делаю не так?

===============================================
Прикрепляю код, который не понимаю почему не работает:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "INTEXTFILE=old_file.txt"
set "OUTTEXTFILE=new_file.txt"
for /f "tokens=1-3*" %%a in ("%INTEXTFILE%") do (if "%%a"=="INSERT" (echo %%a %%b %%c_temp %%d >> "%OUTTEXTFILE%") else (echo %%a %%b %%c %%d >> "%OUTTEXTFILE%"))
del "%INTEXTFILE%"
rename "%OUTTEXTFILE%" "%INTEXTFILE%"
endlocal
```

Comment: Для администрирования Windows уже давно пора всем перейти на PowerShell

Comment: А не легче искать " VALUES (" заменив сначала все двойные пробелы

Comment: @AzizUmarov, можно и "VALUES (" искать, но я всё равно не знаю как проходить по всем строкам файла и выполнять этот самый поиск. Про какие двойные пробелы речь?

Comment: *Про какие двойные пробелы речь?* `INSERT{пробел}{пробел}INTO...`

Comment: @Akina, в файле после INSERT один пробел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно одной команды:

```sh
for /f "tokens=1-3*" %a in (old_file.txt) do (if "%a"=="INSERT" (echo %a %b %c_temp %d >> new_file.txt))
```

Comment: Akina, спасибо, это помогло. А как записывать результат в этот же файл (old_file.txt), не создавая новый?

Comment: Думал, писать строчку с "_temp" после текущей и удалять эту самую текущую. Тем самым происходит как бы замена, но не знаю даже как строчку удалить из файла. Странно, что плохо гуглится или я плохо гуглю...

Comment: @Alex *как записывать результат в этот же файл (old_file.txt), не создавая новый?* По завершении обработки удалить старый файл и переименовать новый (добавить в конец команды ещё `&& del old_file.txt && ren new_file.txt old_file.txt` через пробел). *не знаю даже как строчку удалить из файла.* В моей команде строки. не начинающиеся с INSERT - удаляются (вернее, не обрабатываются и не записываются в выходной файл).

Comment: Akina,я прикрепил код к вопросу. Почему он не работает? Батник просто запускается и закрывается

Comment: @Alex `else` - отдельная команда. `if(выражение) (команды) else (команды)` НЕЛЬЗЯ размещать в одной строке, должно быть `if(выражение) (<CR> команды <CR>) else (<CR> команды <CR>)`.

Comment: Akina, дело не в этом. if else у меня было в одной строке и всё работало. Перестало работать из-за переменных, которые я добавил, INTEXTFILE и  OUTTEXTFILE. Думаю дело в процентах при этих переменных "%OUTTEXTFILE%", "%INTEXTFILE%"

Comment: Включите `echo on` да смотрите, как выполняется подстановка...

Comment: Akina, всё исправил, где не получалось. А вообще с помощью вашего ответа решил свою задачу. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Проходить по строкам файла

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (the-file.txt) DO ( 
  ECHO Line is: %%a
)
```

А вот пример другой ответ [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273937/how-to-replace-substrings-in-windows-batch-file)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "INTEXTFILE=test.txt"
set "OUTTEXTFILE=test_out.txt"
set "SEARCHTEXT=bath"
set "REPLACETEXT=hello"

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type "%INTEXTFILE%"') do (
    set "string=%%A"
    set "modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!"
    echo !modified!>>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
)

del "%INTEXTFILE%"
rename "%OUTTEXTFILE%" "%INTEXTFILE%"
endlocal
```

Comment: Aziz, спасибо за примеры. Был бы у меня рейтинг больше, поставил бы + за ответ (пока нет такой возможности). Буду разбираться